# How to make the model of the partial view independent from the view itself?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

First please do not mark this question as duplicate because I've already checked these:

[pass a different model to the partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594228/pass-a-different-model-to-the-partial-view)

[MVC PartialView in multiple Views with different models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001456/mvc-partialview-in-multiple-views-with-different-models)

[MVC 4 - Use a different model in partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173204/mvc-4-use-a-different-model-in-partial-view)

but none of them helped in my case.

I'm working on a Asp.NET MVC news website.
my home page is called feed,and my partial view is called _Comments.
the _Comment partial view has a text area and a submit button to save the comments depending on the clicked feed.

_Comment partial view :

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddComment", "Home", new AjaxOptions() 
    {UpdateTargetId= "update-comment", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
    {
     <textarea type="text" class="float-none form-control" required 
    name="comment" row="6" placeholder="What do you think?"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary" 
    name="feedID" value="@Session["FeedID"]">Add comment</button>
    }
 </div>
```

I'm calling the partial view in the feed page in this way.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
@Html.Partial("_Comment")
</div>
```

And I'm planning to show the added comments underneath the The _comment partial view, in another partial View Called "_AddedComments"

_AddedComments

```
@model News.CommentViewModel
@if (Model.CommentV != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.CommentV)
    {
        @item.Comment_Text <br />
    }
}
```

so in my feed view I'm calling the 2 partial views like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            @Html.Partial("_Comment")
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-12" id="update-comment">
        @Html.Partial("_AddedComments")
 </div>
```

I have a table called Comments that contains:

CommentID

CommentText

Feed_ID_FK

Now when I press the add comment in the _comment Partial view it takes me to this controller method

```
  public PartialViewResult AddComment(string comment, int feedID)
    {
        Comment newComment       = new Comment();
        newComment.Feed_FK_ID    = feedID;
        newComment.Comment_Text  = comment;
        DB.Comments.Add(newComment);
        DB.SaveChanges();
        List<Comment> myComments = DB.Comments.Where(a => a.Feed_FK_ID == 
         feedID).ToList();

        CommentViewModel viewModel = new CommentViewModel
        {
            CommentV = myComments
        };  

        return PartialView("_AddedComments");
        }
```

My CommentViewModel contains

```
  public List<Comment> CommentV { get; set; }  // Comments table
  public List<Feed> FeedV { get; set; }        // Feeds Table
```

and "myViewModel" in the feeds page contains almost everything (News categories,feeds,users,images...)

So in very top of the feed page I'm calling MyviewModel

```
@model News.myViewModel
```

and in the _AddedComments I'm calling CommentsViewModel

```
@model News.CommentViewModel.
```

The problem is every time i open up the feeds page I'm getting this message :
 " The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'News.myViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'News.CommentViewModel' "
even though I'm passing the CommentViewModel in the partial View.
Any help would be so appreciated .

I tried to call the _AddedComments like this:
    @Html.Partial("_AddedComments",new CommentViewModel())
but I got a null exception. 
The only way I got this task working is by adding a comment list into the original View model, but I guess it's not a good practice because the model " myViewModel" contains like 7 tables and I just want to pass the comments table so I guess it's not a good idea to pass the model "MyViewMdoel".

Comment: `@Html.Partial(` renders the partial view without calling the server side action method of the partial view. If you want to render the partial view `_AddedComments` and `_Comment` with their respective actions executed, you should use `@{Html.RenderAction(<ActionName>);}`

Comment: Thanks for replying,but i'm getting now in the razor view "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object "

Comment: Please refer answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157072/using-renderactionactionname-values-in-mvc4-issue

Answer (score 1):

change your code as below,

```
public ActionResult AddComment(string comment, int feedID)
    {
        Comment newComment       = new Comment();
        newComment.Feed_FK_ID    = feedID;
        newComment.Comment_Text  = comment;
        DB.Comments.Add(newComment);
        DB.SaveChanges();
        List<Comment> myComments = DB.Comments.Where(a => a.Feed_FK_ID == 
         feedID).ToList();

        CommentViewModel viewModel = new CommentViewModel
        {
            CommentV = myComments
        };  

        return PartialView("_AddedComments",viewModel );
        }
```

Comment: i just did that and edit the calling of the partial view by using @{Html.RenderAction(<ActionName>);} ,but now the partial view open in a new page. I checked the UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"  , and I've already added                  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js